# how to add an external library to Visual Studio project RELATIVE to solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference

Is it possible to add a path to the project VC++ Directories to load a external library but have the paths relative to the solution root?

I ask this as I work off a USB that I work on at home and take to uni, and at uni I am always on different systems (witch ever is free) I would like to works wit ha external library, but every time i sit at a new computer I need to set everything up...

I am looking for a way to place the entire external library inside a dir in my solution folder, and then set the project paths relative to that.. so were ever I load the solution, on any system. it can still find the library and compile.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using [**`subst`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491006.aspx):

1. Map your library dir to a virtual drive:

   `subst Z: C:\dev\lib\`
2. From Visual Studio, direct references to Z:\ (e.g.: `Z:\some.dll` is actually `C:\dev\lib\some.dll`)